# MOSFET keeps detonating

Tags: mosfet, switches, failure

I am building a power switch for rocketry usage. On the outside of the rocket is what we call a screw switch. I am not comfortable with all the current running through the screw switch, so I built a MOSFET switch controlled by the screw switch. The problem is that my MOSFET has failed open twice. Last time it happened in mid-flight.

[image: MOSFET Switch]

Operation is on the pad, turn on the screw switch. It powers up the 5 V supply to provide electronics power and also makes battery voltage available to to the avionics to fire in flight pyrotechnic charges to light air started motors and deploy parachutes. Indicator light and avionics current is probably only about 30 mA. When pyro charges fire, they can draw several amps for a second. They usually ignite in about 500 ms.

[image: Last Flight]

You may be able to see that during my last flight, shortly after time zero is when the first two air start motors should have lit. They did not light. Battery voltage just starts dropping there until it is down to 5 V. Post-mortem, the MOSFET opened. Any ideas on how to make this reliable?

Comment: Explain what "MOSFET opened" means to you please. Do you mean an open-circuit i.e. it deactivated?

Comment: If you give us the specifications of the "screw switch", someone here may be able to let you know if there is any reason to be concerned with the current passing through it. If you can get away with fewer parts, there is more chance of success, but I guess rocketry enthusiasts know that already. The screw has to be stiff enough that it can't unscrew in flight.

Comment: I think a more accurate measurement of the igniter current is necessary here; "can draw several amps" isn't close enough when it's a squared term in the equations concerned. I agree with @DKNguyen in that it's possible that voltage sag from the igniters could be dropping Vgs into marginal territory.

Comment: What are the units of igniter A, B, C in the telemetry?   If the pyro doesn't fire, does it continue to take current?  Is the mAh and C rating of your batteries good enough to provide all the Amps plus a conservative margin?

Comment: When does the switch operate, is it turning on during flight or--? How long is its wiring?

Comment: MOSFET Open:
When picked up off the ground the Green LED was out. Opening the switch caused the LED to light but there was only about 2V on the LED. Closing the switch dropped LED voltage to zero.

Screw Switch:
Home made. It is a nylon nut with wires on opposite sides of the nut. The nut is mounted in the airframe of the rocket. A metal screw is in the nut and screwed down tight to turn on. Rocket motors have sulfur in them. Any moisture makes sulfuric acid. Not a great way to have good electrical connections. 

Igniter Current:
E-matches are about 40mA, others can be up to 6A.

Comment: Units of Igniter:
Vertical line is time when fired, horizontal line is voltage applied.

Switch Operation:
Switch is turned on when the rocket is vertical on the pad. Wiring from the switch to the MOSFET is about 10 inches.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the rocket arming screw switch is likely exposed to the atmosphere so, when the rocket is accelerating through the atmosphere, it probably picks up enough friction charge from the air that it blasts through the MOSFETs gate-source region. Try using a Zener diode protection on the gate-source region.

Arming screw switches are likely very exposed because of their intended use: -

[image]

Image taken from [DIY Screw Switches for Rocketry](https://concretedog.blogspot.com/2019/05/diy-screw-switches-for-rocketry.html)

Comment: It is exposed to atmosphere, but the rocket typically only flies up about 600' and only gets to about 80'/sec (50mph). I like the thinking, but I don't think it was an issue this flight.

Comment: Have looked into how much distance you have to move stuff to pick up significant charge? I mean, it's a think like rubbing an ebony rod or taking a nylon shirt off or walking across a carpet.

Comment: Even exposed, it is a dead short to ground when flying. 1M to battery.

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient gate voltage. You need 10V. Vgth is the value where conduction barely starts which is not your goal. You're interested in when the rated RDSon is achieved.

You need a logic level MOSFET. Or a relay.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the actual problem. The battery voltage is not that much below 10V, and if you look at figure 3 in the Infineon datasheet, you can see that even at Vgs=-5V, you'd expect Rds to only be ballpark 10x higher, so ~200mΩ. That doesn't seem high enough to kill the mosfet at a few amps for a second. Unless the current draw is much higher than OP thinks.

Answer (score 1):

RE-EDITED ANSWER

The MOSFET failed to open because the R1 is 1M Ohms and it's way too much.
When SW1 closes, Q1 is conducting because gate voltage is lower than source voltage (battery voltage in your case).
But when SW1 reopens, the gate doesn't have time to return to source voltage because R1 slows the current too much.
Let's imagine that there is still some conduction through or around SW1 on the order of 3M Ohms and the voltage at the gate will never reach battery voltage.
That's why I suggest 10K for R1.

Another reason for reducing R1 is that when the battery voltage falls quickly, the gate voltage doesn't remain too high versus source voltage. (see in the datasheet how much higher than source it can go). With 1 M Ohms, it may have stayed at 8.7V for quite a while after BAT fell to 5V.
But this may not be the reason of the failure.

Adding a 0.01uF or 0.1uF capacitor across SW1 (between R2 and GND) is still valid to protect the gate and avoid multiple ON and OFF as the switch is in the process of closing itself but not completely close (and vice versa) aka "bouncing". But this may slow down the rising slope at the gate. If the P-MOSFET has to react quickly or ASAP, it's better not to use more than 0.01 uF.
If on the contrary, it's better to slow it down a little bit (like for 500 ms) to avoid bouncing, then put the capacitor between R2 and the gate instead of between R2 and SW1.

Protect the gate with R2 and a 10 volt Zener diode.
The voltage of the Zener diode should be just a bit higher than maximum battery voltage. But not equal.

Vgs limit is -20V. This is the lower limit But the Zener, as on my schematic, will protect on the + side, so that Vgs won't be higher than the upper limit due to the effect described by Andy Aka.
I don't know what the upper limit might be so check the datasheet.

To protect on the lower limit you should put a 15 volts Zenner in the opposite direction, fron gate to source. But I don't think it's necessary (and it may be even worse) to do so.

(First test the circuit *in-lab* before firing new rockets.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffezha.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I like this. I'll give it a try and see how it goes. If the grass stays green, I may get in another flight or two this spring. If it get brown too soon, then I won't be able to report back until next fall.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an external switch, you may want to put a ESD protection diode to make sure external voltage don't max out Vgs

Comment: During flight, the screw switch is closed and the gate is a dead short to ground. Think that component is still needed? Both times the MOSFET failed, it was while it was turned on.

Comment: If you are touching the switch on a regular basis, yes

Answer (score 0):

With an exposed screw switch driving the gate, make R1 47kΩ, and add gate-source overvoltage protection.