# MOSFET Explodes

Tags: mosfet

This is similar to my [MOSFET switch issue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/706755/mosfet-keeps-detonating). This is a rocket launching MOSFET control system:

[image: MOSFET Launching System]

This operates by first pads are selected via Q1-Q6. One or more are turned on making those pads ready to launch.  At launch time, Q7 is turned on. After around 10 launches Q7 may physically come apart at the seams.

[image: MOSFET Failure]

Note: Each igniter attached can sink anywhere from 40mA to more than 6A. Normal is about 1A. Typically the igniters burn through in about 500mSec.

Comment: Remove SP1 from the circuit and try again.

Comment: I agree with @Janka. SP1 really should have it's own drive transistor, it's taking gate drive current away from Q7. The next order of business would be ground loops - what's the Vgs voltage during launch? The igniters may be loading down the transistor driver so it's not operating in saturation (like a switch), rather it's launching in it's ohmic region.

Comment: You have no fusing or current limiting. The assumption that the igniter will burn cleanly and that the wiring will not short circuit is probably not valid. There is also the possibility that there is enough inductance in the circuits to cause a flashover  that destroys the mosfet.  Some varistors would address that issue.

Comment: What sort of heatsink is Q7 attached to?

Comment: How long and thin are the wires to the battery? You might have severe voltage drop going to the controller during launch. Also, a big ass capacitor across the controller rails will help mitigate the surge. Something like 47,000uF should eat the surge long enough to fuse the most stubborn igniters.

Comment: As an aside, there is no consideration of safety/failure in the circuit. The comparators could be configured to detect current and a suitably low test current is injected.

Comment: If it breaks every 7+ goes, could you just replace it as a matter of course afer 5 goes? Some things do wear out: for example, rocket fuel tends to be a single-use item. (I do see that longevity is a good goal.)

Comment: What are these components Bz1..Bz6?

Comment: Remove SP1 - That is a piezoelectric active buzzer and it is on the other side of an auctioneering diode. The gate is tired directly to ULN2004 with 500mA of sink for a gate that will never draw more then 100uA. 
Fusing - is on the battery itself. 
No heat sink on Q7. I hazarded a guess that only being on for typically .500mS, it would not heat up. 
Battery Wires- 20G extention cord and they are only about 2' long. 
LiPo batteries rated at 70C. 
BZx components? I don't have any. Perhaps you are seeing the IGx components. They are igniters. Typically about 2ohm bridge wire in pyrogen.

Comment: Igniter leads are typically about 20' long 20G wires. About 12uH of inductance.

Answer (score 1):

ULN2004A is wholly unsuitable as a MOSFET gate driver. If the inputs are 3-5V then use CD4504. If the inputs are 12V, use CD40106.

But that's not the main problem. The main problem is that you need a protected source for ignition. The source should survive shorts to ground, have overvoltage protection **on the output**, have thermal protection for the power element, etc.

The igniters are connected with long wires, right? Those generate large inductive voltage spikes as the igniter coil opens, and kill your mosfets.

But you need all types of protection to make this robust.

U3 is of course not necessary either. The comparators can drive the LEDs just fine. If you want to invert the output, just flip the (+) and (-) inputs of the comparator.

The whole circuit lacks several protection components, lacks proper power decoupling, the PCB layout is part of ensuring functionality, etc.

You'll have to add the details to the question, such as:

1. Specifications. What is the thing supposed to do? Imagine you asked someone to make such a box for you. What do you want the behavior of the box be?
2. Pictures of your current assembly (PCB with components on it, both sides).
3. PCB layout.

Then it'll be easier to figure out what you really want, vs. what the broken implementation is doing.

MOSFETs are not considered reliable isolation elements. There should be a master ARM signal that uses a relay to energize the storage capacitor that feeds the LAUNCH mosfet.

---

Here's a sketch of how this could be made. This is not a tested circuit, just a starting point. I believe it should be going in the right direction, but given the complexity it's hard to be certain in the short time I had available to draw it out.

### Arm-Launch Section

First, the relay R21 is used for arming the system. Then a mosfet M1 is used to connect the arm bus to launch bus.

CD40106 is a Schmitt-trigger input inverter. CD4041 is a 10mA complementary output driver. It ensures that the launch mosfet turns on quickly and doesn't dissipate much heat while it turns on or off under load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwYfHP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The C1 is the transient energy source for the launch bus. The bottom end of it (LAUNCH_RETURN) is connected via an energy-monitoring current sink to the ground. The current sink limits the charge current of C1, as well as limiting the battery discharge current due to loads attached to C1.

### Launch Bus Current Limiter

OA23 provides 2.5x gain for the current sensing shunt resistor R29. OA22 closes the current limiting loop. The current is limited to 10A. When the current is below 10A, M21 is fully turned on and acts as a "short circuit", firmly connecting the launch bus return to the battery/power supply negative terminal.

When the current is at the 10A limit, M21's conductance decreases to keep the current at the limit. This causes heat dissipation across M21.

OA21 measures the voltage across M21. When the voltage is higher than some maximum value, the current on M21 is known to be 10A, and the heating power within M21 is proportional to the drain-source voltage. This voltage is converted to current by M21-Q23 and accumulates modeled heat in the thermal mass model C21.

### Current Limiter Thermal Protection

The current sink integrates the power dissipated in M21 when the 10A current limit is active. When that energy exceeds a threshold, the launch bus is disarmed, and has to be re-armed by cycling the ARM input. When the current limit is not active, the sink acts like a short-circuit and dissipates very little heat (a couple watts at most).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpXY7D.png)</sup>

C21 is the integrator. The voltage across it (relative to +12V) is the accumulated thermal energy dissipated by M21. The cooling heat flow is provided by the current source Q21-Q22. When the current control loop goes into current limit, the voltage across M21 rises and the heating flow current sink OA21-Q23 exceeds the cooling heat flow, and C21 begins to charge.

Once C21 has accumulated a certain amount of heat, modeling the heat accumulated by M21, the inverter N21 disarms the system through flip-flop SR21. The system remains disarmed and cannot be re-armed until C21's model of M21 has "cooled down". Then, a low state of the ARM input will enable re-arming of the system.

Thus, when thermal protection kicks in, arming is disabled until *both* the ARM command signal is removed, and the thermal model estimates that the mosfet has safely cooled down.

Parameters of the thermal model:

R27 is inversely proportional to the heating strength (i.e. the higher the resistance, the less heat is produced by the model of the current flowing through M21).

R24 is inversely proportional to the cooling strength (the higher the resistance, the less cooling heat flow there is).

C21 is proportional to the thermal mass of M21. There can be a resistor across C21 to better model the temperature-dependent cooling heat flow, instead of the current source Q21-Q22-R24.

The calculation of the component values for the thermal protection model of M21 is left to the reader :)

### Launch Circuits

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiopOj.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MOSFET Q7 can turn off properly. Consider this part of the schematic: -

[image]

I think it's a problem waiting to happen from day 1. It would only manifest itself at the end of a launch I suspect; the MOSFET would still be trying to feed DC to the other MOSFETs but, as the gate voltage would rise sloppily (and barely reach 10 volts), the MOSFET would go into its saturation region and dissipate a lot of power.

The same is true for all the other MOSFETs but, Q7 is handling all the current that they take individually hence it will suffer and burn first.

**Addition:** The ULN2004 can have a leakage current as high as 100 micro amps and this acts like a pull-down. Throw in a the fact that the signal into the ULN2004 may not be absolutely pristine and it begins to look very flaky to me. The clamp-diode leakage current of 100 micro amps also is taking current from the gate to the point on the circuit I marked as "Less than 10 volts".

Comment: R6 is the pull up.

Comment: @MOSFET the trouble is that the ULN2004 can have a leakage current as high as 100 micro amps and this acts like a pull-down. Throw in a the fact that the signal into the ULN2004 may not be absolutely pristine and it looks very flaky to me. Add to that the clamp-diode leakage current of 100 micro amps taking current from the gate to the point on the circuit I marked as "Less than 10 volts".

Comment: R6 is the pull up for the gate to keep Q7 off. There are plenty of comments about gate current. am I really confused? (I'm an ex-Navy Nuke, not an engineer) but the gate should essential have no current, on or off. The spec sheet for the IRF4905 P-Channel Enhancement 74A MOSFET says that at the most there will be 100nA.

Comment: You can assume there is no gate current but, that is not what I'm talking about.